# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio, I am getting this error everytime I try to sync the project with gradle. For instance I am providing reference to three files.

**1) Project level build.gradle File**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**2) Gradle Scripts build.gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0-RC2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**3) gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Nov 05 11:37:25 IST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

I am on Windows 10 with Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.0.1 Patch 3

**The Complete Error Message Which I get is**

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Smells like a firewall problem.

Comment: chrylis Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Step 1: Post a complete error message, particularly including the part that probably says something like "connection timed out".

Comment: Yeah I added the complete error message

Comment: Chrylis I have added the complete error message at the end of the question, Now can you please provide me with a solution because I am not able to get started with android studio. It's my first project afterall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , as it seems alright I can only guess its a connection issue .

Try using this link https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom with a browser to make sure you can connect to google .

if you can reach the site then you ll probably need to use proxy/vpn .

and the way to do so is downloading [psiphon](https://psiphon.ca/en/download.html?psiphonca) and navigate to the setting , set local port for 1234 for example.

Then go to Users/%USERNAME%/.gradle and add gradle properties , with the following

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1234

systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1234
```

Comment: Yes I can connect to dl.google.com successfully and yeah I think I need a proxy let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Still getting the same issue, also tried adding the proxy. 
I can download .jar file when pasting the link on the browser but on android studio getting this error.

Comment: This was a valid response with the android version at that time , try to set the HTTP proxy settings in Android Studio: From the menu bar, click File > Settings (on macOS, click Android Studio > Preferences). In the left pane, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy. The HTTP Proxy page appears.
the proxy should be as the answer suggested after connecting with psiphon.

Comment: the problem for me was that cruel maintainer of maven repository now return 404 instead of 403 when you have an ip ban so I waisted many hours not knowing what was going on