# Getting error while trying to build Gradle project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm using eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)

This is my gradle version

```
Gradle 7.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 16.0.2+7-67)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

My java version is 16.0.2

While creating gradle project getting this preview failed.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle installation 'C:\Users\hp\Documents\tools\gradle-7.2-bin\gradle-7.2'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.initProjectIfNotExists(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.runInToolingApi(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiOperations$1.runInToolingApi(ToolingApiOperations.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2338)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage$4.run(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Gradle could not start your build.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:103)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.initialization.exception.InitializationException: Gradle could not start your build.
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<BuildActionRunner>.
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:798)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:683)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:706)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:442)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeServiceProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:991)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1077)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:321)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:896)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1124)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1106)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1069)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1600(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:796)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.readState(LockStateAccess.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.ensureLockState(LockStateAccess.java:46)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.ensureLockState(LockFileAccess.java:57)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:315)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:164)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:110)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:168)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:375)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:211)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:292)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:61)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileAccessTimeJournal.<init>(DefaultFileAccessTimeJournal.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal(GradleUserHomeScopeServices.java:241)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
    ... 95 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do , First of all you can make sure that you have the environment variable needed , GRADLE_USER_HOME is usually located at `Users/%USERNAME%/.gradle` .

Then you can make sure that you add the `/gradle_installation_Foler/bin` to path .

Then try to go with gradle build , using command link at the location of your `build.gradle` , this will definitely make sure if you are able to download the dependency and have no issue with access .

if you do have connection issue , and you need to use a VPN [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861595/could-not-get-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-g/69862866#69862866) is an old answer of mine for how to do that .

let me know in comments if new error occurred .

Comment: Do I need to add GRADLE_USER_HOME and JAVA_HOME manually while creating gradle project?

Comment: I think its a MUST HAVE , even IDE use them to get the appropriate variables .

Comment: I'm adding that manually but its not reflecting in that preview page. It is showing java home directory and gradle user home directory as 'Unknown'

Comment: may you share some screen shots ? you go to enviroment variables and hit new , name = GRADLE_USER_HOME , value = C:\Users\George\.gradle , in my case

Comment: like that in the above screenshot in "Java home directory: Unknown"

Comment: I created environment variables for GRADLE_HOME with value C:\Users\hp\Documents\tools\gradle-7.2-bin\gradle-7.2                                            Path variable C:\Users\hp\Documents\tools\gradle-7.2-bin\gradle-7.2\bin and GRADLE_USER_HOME with value C:\Users\hp\.gradle

Comment: ok now , forget about the IDE for a bit , go to the location where your build,gradle exist , open cmd in that location , and try to build using command line `gradle build` , if this work , here is waht you need to do after , close eclipse , then type ```gradle wrapper``` then go to eclipse again , import existing gradle project , keep the defaults and you should be able to run with no error . if the first command line command did not work , then you have miss configured the gradle environments variables and you need to try again .

Comment: Got error when giving gradle build command.                                                                                               Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<BuildActionRunner>.
   > Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
      > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

Comment: Thanks George. Now its working I deleted the folders inside cache in .gradle

Comment: Great , glad i helped , please mark as accepted so other can use this solution .