# Get list of dependencies without finding JARs?

Tags: gradle

I am behind a proxy and when I run Gradle my build fails with:

```
Failure: Build failed with an exception.
Could not find ......jar
Searched in the following locations:
    https:/...
```

This is expected behaviour because the proxy blocks that particular artifact. Now I need to get that artifact unblocked within my organisation.

The problem is when I get the artifact unblocked and run the build again I get the same error but this time for a different artifact.

Is there a way I can get the whole list of dependencies in Gradle without it trying to get the actual JARs? That way I will know all of the artifacts which need to be checked are available (and deal with getting them unblocked).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is , You can try to `gradle dependencies` with command line and this will return a list of all the needed dependencies for this build .

and am not pretty sure why your facing this issue , if your whole network is behind a proxy a simple gradle specific proxy setup will fix this issue for you , i think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861595/could-not-get-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-g/69862866#69862866) might be helpful .

Comment: This command results in the same error. The reason I am facing the issue is because of an internal control which blocks access to those JARs where the proxy cannot find the LICENSE for. In this case it is happening incorrectly.

Comment: i had no idea , i tried with `gradle dependencies -x build ` and returned the same results without building up my app . maybe this will work in your case .

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.